# Corresponding week column for each different participant with starting dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-preprocessing

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':['A','A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
    'Date':['9/20/2021  4:34:57 AM', '9/21/2021  6:54:22 PM', '9/28/2021  5:54:22 PM', 
           '9/30/2021  6:54:22 PM', '10/5/2021  6:54:22 PM',
           '9/4/2021  7:04:38 PM','9/9/2021  7:04:38 PM','9/17/2021  7:04:38 PM',
           '9/28/2021  3:21:23 AM','9/30/2021  3:21:23 AM','10/05/2021  3:21:23 
            AM','10/15/2021  3:21:23 AM']}
    
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
 df1
```

The 'Date' column is in datetime format.

Now for each participant, the first entry is the enrolled date and that would be the start of week 1 for that particular participant. I want corresponding week number for the subsequent date entries, considering the first entry as Day 0.

The final dataframe should look like the image given below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, a new "week" in this context is just every 7 days? So like if the enrolled date was a Friday, the following Monday would still be considered week 1?

Comment: Yes. It would be Week 1 till the next friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Week'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'] \
               .apply(lambda t: 1 + (t - min(t)).dt.days // 7)

df['Week'] = 'Week' + df['Week'].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID                Date   Week
0   A 2021-09-20 04:34:57  Week1
1   A 2021-09-21 18:54:22  Week1
2   A 2021-09-28 17:54:22  Week2
3   A 2021-09-30 18:54:22  Week2
4   A 2021-10-05 18:54:22  Week3
5   B 2021-09-04 19:04:38  Week1
6   B 2021-09-09 19:04:38  Week1
7   B 2021-09-17 19:04:38  Week2
8   C 2021-09-28 03:21:23  Week1
9   C 2021-09-30 03:21:23  Week1
10  C 2021-10-05 03:21:23  Week2
11  C 2021-10-15 03:21:23  Week3
```

*Fixed by @ddejohn*

Comment: I was using `lambda t: 1 + (t - min(t)).dt.days // 7` and got the correct week number there.

Comment: It should be Week 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df1['Week'] = (df1.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
                  .groupby(df1['ID']).cumsum()
                  .fillna(0, downcast='infer') // 7 + 1)

df1['Week'] = 'Week' + df1['Week'].astype(str)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

   ID                Date   Week
0   A 2021-09-20 04:34:57  Week1
1   A 2021-09-21 18:54:22  Week1
2   A 2021-09-28 17:54:22  Week2
3   A 2021-09-30 18:54:22  Week2
4   A 2021-10-05 18:54:22  Week3
5   B 2021-09-04 19:04:38  Week1
6   B 2021-09-09 19:04:38  Week1
7   B 2021-09-17 19:04:38  Week2
8   C 2021-09-28 03:21:23  Week1
9   C 2021-09-30 03:21:23  Week1
10  C 2021-10-05 03:21:23  Week2
11  C 2021-10-15 03:21:23  Week3
```